# LibreOffice-Calc 7.1.4.2: How to display input bar results in a cell, *or* what is fraction-to-decimal formula?

Tags: libreoffice

I want to enter a fraction in one cell and display its decimal equivalent in another cell. If I format a cell for fraction input, and enter a fraction such as ⅜ in that cell, I see the decimal equivalent (0.375) in the Input bar. How can I show that decimal equivalent in a cell, *or* what is the formula for converting a fraction to decimal, and displaying the result in a cell?

Comment: Converting a fraction to a decimal is, happily, easy division: 3 divided by 8 is 0.375. You can format the cells differently -- one to show a fraction, the other to show the same number as a decimal.

Answer (score 1):

In one cell (For eg: A1) you shall format it to display the fraction. In another cell(For eg: B1), you shall copy the content of A1 using the command

```
=A1
```

The content of B1 shall be tweaked to display decimals by formatting it to display 'numbers'.

Comment: Format to display fraction: `1 3/8` or `0 3/8`. The space between the whole number and the fraction is critical, else Calc will think you are inputting a date.